# Making collections easily printable using CSS

Tags: css, tabular

I have a XML collection of personnel information and my goal is to make a stylesheet that allows the printing of the table rows continue into a second column rather than a second page? I have no interest in complex solutions, just wandering if this can be done in plain CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XSL (XML Stylesheet) to transform one XML document into another.  This means you can then use it to transform XML into (x)HTML!

The down side is its pretty tricky to do and requires some javascript if you want to actually display this on a page with other html content.

It's probably easier just to use jQuery to parse the XML and create a table that way.

Comment: Seems that simply using float property inside the outermost element you are going to list does the trick!